# Is it possible to inherit or reference a perforce workspace (clientspec)?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I want to keep my workspace (clientspec) definition as simple as possible, following the main one used by the project.

The problem is that you never know when the original workspace was modified and I was looking for a way to configure my workspace by "importing" definitions form the parent one and just adding my overrides.

Is this possible to do on Perforce, and if possible how?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you really want to check out the upcoming Streams feature. I know it's not an answer to your problem now, but it should solve it in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the '-t' flag on the 'p4 client' command.

Comment: But if you want to customize the clientspec, this won't help you to keep up to date with the parent.